# About use of complex number in AC steady state analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, phasor

My question is essentially about the polar representation of complex numbers used in steady state analysis of AC circuits.

As far as I know a complex number \$a+jb\$ is represented as \$M \angle \theta\$, where M is the magnitude of the complex number and \$\theta\$ is the angle that it makes with the positive x-axis.

But in circuit analysis we replace \$A\cos(\omega t+\theta)\$ by \$A\angle\theta\$, which does not agree with how complex numbers are represented. According to me, \$A\cos(\omega t+\theta)\$ should rather be written as \$Re(A\angle\theta)\$, because it is the real part of the complex number \$A e^{j(\omega t+\theta)}\$ (I know that we drop the \$\omega t\$ part as it remains the same for all the currents and voltages in a circuit consisting of linear components).

Comment: Are you assuming that the circuit has no reactive components?

Comment: If you just look at the real part a of a+jb then you lose information on reactive currents etc. which are actually real (in the sense that they exist, just out of phase) and have real-world consequences (hence power factor correction, for example).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No.

Comment: Please ask a specific question

Comment: You must be, because the only time you can ignore the imaginary component of the phasor is if the circuit is in resonance.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I get your point, but why do represent \$A\cos(\omega t+\theta)\$ just by \$A\angle \theta\$ ?

Comment: The phase information is in the angle \$\theta\$, the magnitude (\$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\$) is in A. I don't see the issue.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany when writing complex numbers in polar form we use \$ A\angle\theta\$ type representation, but \$ A\cos(\omega t+\theta)\$ is a purely real quantity, so why use \$ A\angle\theta\$ for that ?

Comment: The current in an AC circuit if you measure it with an ammeter (which ignores phase) is A. The phase (relative to supply) is \$\theta\$. The (real) power is related to \$A\cos{\theta}\$ where \$\theta\$ is also called the power factor. Complex numbers are used to handle magnitude + phase information.

Comment: Actually power factor is \$cos(\theta) = P/S\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point of the question is why it is valid to replace the term  \$A\cos(\omega t+\theta)\$ by \$A\angle\theta\$.

The expression \$A \angle \theta\$ is a notation for \$ A e^{j\theta}\$, which is called the phasor representation.

Actually there is no identity that would directly result in this representation instead a phasor transform is defined as follows
$$
 A e^{j\theta} = {\cal P} \left\{A cos(\omega t + \theta)\right\}
$$
along with inverse transform
$$
  {\cal P}^{-1}\{A e^{j\theta} \} = Re\left\{A e^{j\phi} e^{j\omega t}\right\}
$$
Often a formal definition is omitted, since phasors are quite common and well-known, but good textbooks usually include them.

Comment: ...and that's called Steinmetz transform :)

Answer (score 0):

We use complex numbers to simplify the math in ac circuits (mostly for parallel and series/parallel circuits).  Series ac circuits are typically done with Vector addition (Pythagoras and trigonometry).

If you substitute different values of t into A cos(ωt + θ), you will get a cosine wave, that has a magnitude of A and starts θ before the y-axis.  But we cannot use this in calculations, so we turn it into a vector with magnitude A at a phase angle θ.

The reason complex numbers can be used to represent ac circuits is because resistance R acts along x-axis (real component) and capacitive reactance \$X_C \$ and inductive reactance \$X_L \$ act along y-axis.

This just happens to correspond to the complex number plane, so we can use complex numbers to simplify math in ac circuits.  Z = R + j (\$X_L \$ - \$X_C \$)

You could also Pythagoras and trigonometry to come to the same answer.

$$ Z = \sqrt {R^2 + (X_L - X_C)^2}\ \ \ \ \theta = tan^{-1} \frac {(X_L - X_C)} {R}$$

The complexity goes up when you have to deal with parallel circuits.